# unable to query hive table from power pivot when connected to apache hive using hortonworks hive odbc 32/64 bit driver

Tags: sql, odbc, hive, driver, powerpivot

I have been trying to query an apache hive database using hortonworks odbc driver through power pivot excel 2010.

I am able to connect without any issue to any table present in hive db.

Also able to do the following to pull the whole tabke data from power pivot connection wizard:
Select * from [schema].[table-name].

But when I am trying to filter the data using 'where' clause unless the column is a partitioned column, its not working.

And neither am I able to select any particular column after select statement.

I tried to all possible things like eclosung column name by square braces or qualifying them with table name and dot. But nothing seems to be working.

Please advice. Any help would be extremely helpful.
And if there is no way to filter the data all the logic of partitioning and bucketing the data in hive would go in vein.

Thanks in advance.